# What is percentage of net worth?

Tags: net-worth

Let's say you have the following balance sheet:

```
$350,000 - home value
$200,000 - retirement
$15,000 - savings
(assets = $565,000)

$250,000 - mortgage
$10,000 - car loan
$40,000 - student loans
$15,000 - credit cards
(liabilities = $315,000)
```

Net worth = $250,000

If you then buy a car for $45,000, is that considered 21% (45/250) of your net worth or 8% (45/565)?

What percentage would the mortgage be considered as?

Comment: What is your goal here? Is it 'how to think about my net worth?' or are you reporting these numbers to someone? A similar question to look at https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/20347/should-i-include-my-hard-assets-as-part-of-my-net-worth

Comment: Mortgage or car loan?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You properly calculated net worth of $250k, the percentage of net worth for a given asset would then be based on how much of that $250k it contributes. For example the house is worth $350k but has a $250k mortgage, so it contributes 100k of the 250k net worth, or 40% of net worth. That's all well and good when the liabilities each tie to a specific asset, but you've got liabilities that don't logically offset a specific asset. I've only ever considered net worth as a whole, so I'm not sure of a use-case for this calculation, but I would probably apply the other liabilities equally after taking off the ones tied to specific assets.

So here I've used the mortgage to offset the home value, then aggregated remaining liabilities and calculated the percentage to offset all assets by:
[image: Net Worth]

Regarding the car purchase, if you buy a $45k car, you are either shifting assets around or incurring new debt, neither of which alters your current net worth (ignoring immediate depreciation on the car which reduces net worth). So that means the percentage of your net worth that it contributes will depend on how it is purchased, if fully financed with no money down it would represent 0% of your net-worth because it is offset by the attached debt, if you bought it outright using other assets then it would represent ~14% of your net worth using the approach above and assuming the existing $10k car loan was unrelated to this new car purchase.

Some people suggest you should spend less than x% of net worth on a vehicle as a rule, so if you have $250k net worth that would be the denominator in any such calculations. This isn't a rule I'd heard of before today, but saw it and thought it might be part of why you were asking. It's not a rule I have ever thought about or followed.

Comment: Trying to understand the implication here. If I buy a $10K car with a $10K loan, are you suggesting the car is not an asset? How does this change if the $10K came from a HELOC?

Comment: @Joe, in that case, the car is an asset, but since there is a matching debt, net worth doesn’t change.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: In real life, it's a net debit.  You buy a car for $10K, borrowing the money.  You owe $10K, but realistically can only sell the car for $8K or less.

Comment: So if you just got out of college with a negative net worth due to student loans, you shouldn't buy any car at all?

Comment: No doubt, but so far, I don't see an answer in the form OP asked. i.e. what percent of his assets does the car represent?

Comment: @HartCO: Thanks on the answer. Your response gets the heart of my question: If $250k is 40% of net worth, then what is retirement - 80%? That wouldn't make sense right? Where does that leave savings because now we're at 120%.

Comment: @ThePhoton According to proponents of that rule, I guess not, but it's not a rule I'd advocate in favor of.

Comment: This is my concern. Say I have a $400K house. Whether I owe $40K or $500K, I still have a $400K exposure to real estate and everything that means, good or bad. If I have $1M in stocks, that’s my exposure, whether I own it outright or on margin. This goes to my original comment, why the OP is researching this.

Comment: In a different Q/A on net worth, I noted that I treat the house separately, I don’t count it as asset, but I do count the mortgage as liability. That’s with an eye towards understanding what I have as retirement and to use for 4% rule. Why would I even bother counting cars or personal affects as assets? Unless, of course, my kid asks “so what will I get when you die?” Which she wouldn’t.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer That's a good point, I took it as purely academic, trying to understand net worth ideas. I never fuss about my net worth as there is no context I've encountered where it matters.

Comment: @HartCO: My comment above wasn't about buying a car.

Comment: @4thSpace Hopefully the last edit clears that up, I was focused on the impact of the car purchase on net worth, not the percentage of net worth calculation per asset. I'd still be curious as to the "why" of this, but I think the above approach is reasonable.

Comment: @HartCO: You are calculating assets as a percentage of total assets. That's not the same as assets as a percentage of net worth. I think the latter is not possible. It's a phrase I often hear. X is a percentage of your net worth. For example, savings are a percentage of your net worth. But if your net worth is only $10,000 and your savings are $15,000, that doesn't really make any sense as a comparison.

Comment: @4thSpace No, if it were percentage of total assets retirement would be 35% not 63%, this approach accounts for all liabilities first, and assets less liabilities is net worth, that's why the totals work out (250k net worth).

Comment: The car is 21% of net worth regardless of how it's financed. If it's fully financed by a loan, the car and loan *together* are 0%, but the car *itself* is still 21%.

Comment: @Acccumulation I get what you are saying, but don't see how that approach would be helfpul as you end up with wild percentages that don't paint much of a picture, but I still don't see a use case for this sort of calculation.

Comment: @HartCO: How did you get $158,730 for retirement? By the way, this doesn't have anything to do with a car. I'm not sure how this turned into a car conversation.

Comment: @4thSpace You asked about what happens if you then bought a car, so that's what the initial focus was on. What I did was take the liabilities that don't directly offset an asset (everything but mortgage) add them up at the bottom (65k), and see what percentage of of remaining assets (315k) they comprise 
 (20.6%), so 79.4% of assets go towards net worth if we want to apply those 'other' liabilities evenly to get a percentage of net worth per asset calculation rather than just an asset mix calculation. So  `Asset Net`  *  `Offset %` = `Asset Less Other Liability Offset`

Answer (score 2):

This answer is a counterpoint to Hart's answer, an alternative view.

[image: Net Worth]

Say home prices crash, down 50%. What is the impact on your Net Assets? $175K just went up in smoke, so 250-175=75K, your net dropped 70%. Even though the house is only listed as being 32% of 'net assets'.

On the other hand, the S&P doubles, now your net goes from 250 to 450K. An 80% increase, even though the retirement account was only 63.5%.

In my opinion, percent of net is problematic. Because if there is any debt at all the numbers add to over 100%. The way I'd approach this is to look at the percent represented by each asset. The asset column adds to 565K and that will give you the accurate percent of exposure for each item it contains. Any other method obfuscates the impact of each asset. I can return and edit other examples to show how the method presented distorts that impact.

Comment: I agree that percentage of net worth is not incredibly useful or common. It doesn't show exposure, but net worth isn't about exposure. My approach does add up to 100%, but it only tells you what an asset's current contribution to net worth is. Your approach obfuscates that the home has attached debt. In either case you get a limited view, the question is what do you want to see.

Comment: The house is 140% of net worth. The equity is 40%. That's some funny math to get to 32%. Similarly, the retirement account is 80% of net worth. I don't see a problem with assets being more than 100% of net worth.

Comment: @HartCO - Agreed!